# Why does autowired repository result in a NullPointerException in Junit4 context?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit4, testcontainers

I'm new to Java development so sorry in advance if I'm not using the appropriate terms.

Whenever I run a test on a class that needs to save something in my database, I face a NullPointerException on the Autowired repository.

I use Junit4, here are code snippets :

***application-test.properties***

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.29://localhost:3306/MYSERVICE
```

***MyService.java***

```
@Component
class MyService {
    @Autowired MyRepository myRepository;
    
    public void mainFunction() {
        myRepository.saveSomething();
    }
}
```

***MyRepository.java***

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    
    void saveSomething();
}
```

***MyServiceTest.java***

```
public class myServiceTest extends  TestConfiguration {
    @Rule
    public MySQLContainer mysql = new MySQLContainer();

    @InjectMocks MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void mainFunctionTest() {
        myService.mainFunction()
    }
}
```

***MyServiceTestApplication.java***

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class MyServiceTestApplication{
}
```

***TestConfiguration.java***

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyServiceTestApplication.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class TestConfiguration {

}
```

When I run the test in debug mode, I can see that myRepository is null

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks :)

Edit 01/08/2022 : Add @Component on MyService

Edit 01/08/2022 (2) : Add MyServiceTestApplication.java and TestConfiguration.java

Comment: See and check against this tutorial: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/springboot-test-configuration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, you forgot to annotate the class `MyService` with [`@Service`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html).

With this annotation being made at that class, the *Spring* framework will recognize it:

> This annotation serves as a specialization of @Component, allowing for
> implementation classes to be autodetected through classpath scanning.

Given that the rest of the configuration is working, the `@Autowired` dependency injection mechanism will hereby provide you with an instance of the [`@Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) you requested, at runtime, here your test setup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Unfortunately, I added @Component on MyService and myRepository is still null :(

Comment: Add `@Service` instead of `@Component`

Comment: Besides, check that annotation-based configuration is in place. It seems, relevant parts are missing in your configuration for the test setup.

Comment: Indeed I forgot to show you 2 files, I just added them (MyServiceTestApplication.java and TestConfiguration.java)